# If $x^2+y^2=z^2$ has a solution then $5$ divides $xyz$

Tags: number-theory

I tried to solve a question but I did not succeed yet...my question is about number theory. Here it is:
How can we show that if the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ has a solution then $5$ divides $xyz$?
Can we have a general method for solving questions like that?

I need the beginning of the solution.

I will be very glad if you help.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/pythTripleDiv.shtml  and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4318/proof-of-if-a2-b2-c2-then-abc-is-divisible-by-60

Comment: Another useful link : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html

Comment: can x,y or z be decimals?

Comment: @EpicGuy: all this talk about "divides" kinda implies that we're dealing with integers only (which we are)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $5$ divides $x$ and/or $y,$ we are done

Else

Observe that $$(\pm1)^2\equiv1,(\pm2)^2\equiv4\pmod 5$$

If both $x,y\equiv1\pmod 5, x^2+y^2\equiv2\pmod 5\not\equiv z^2$

If both $x,y\equiv2\pmod 5, x^2+y^2\equiv8\pmod 5\equiv3 \not\equiv z^2$

If $x\equiv\pm1,y\equiv\pm2,x^2+y^2\equiv0\pmod 5$

Now prove that if a prime $p$ divide $a^2,p$ must divide $a$

Here $p=5$

Answer (score 1):

If you know about [general solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306401/show-that-m2-n2-2mn-m2-n2-is-a-primitive-pythagorean-triplet) then you can see we can write primitive solution as $x=2st , y=s^2-t^2 , z=s^2+t^2$ , if $5$ divides one of $s$ or $t$ then $5|x$ and we are done. If $5$ does not divide any of $s$ and $t$ then by Fermat's little theorem $5|s^4-1 , 5|t^4-1$, so that $5|s^4-t^4$ i.e. $5|yz$ , this proves the claim.

Comment: I have  added a stackexchange reference to your answer

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee: Thank you.