# In any Pythagorean triplet at least one of them is divisible by $2$, $3$ and $5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that if $x$, $y$, $z$ are integers such that $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, then at least one of them is divisible by $2$, at least one is divisible by $3$, and at least one is divisible by $5$.

I know that $x,y,z$ are sides of a right-angled triangles. If I start putting values, then I can show, but have no clue about mathematical approach.

How do I solve it mathematically, using modular arithmetic?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534254/if-x2y2-z2-has-a-solution-then-5-divides-xyz

Answer (score 4):

All you need to know are the following facts: For $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$a^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod2$$
$$a^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod3$$
$$a^2 \equiv 0,\pm 1 \pmod5$$
Also, if $a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, where $p$ is a prime, then $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Now check each individual case and conclude what you want.

Comment: any explanation or hyperlink for the facts there?

Comment: Square $1,2,3,4,5$. Then divide each by $2,3,5$ and consider their remainders.